# Search ChebiEntity search by common or synonym name?

Tags: embl

I can download information from ChEBI if I know the corresponding ChEBI ID:

```
from libchebipy import ChebiEntity
chebi_entity = ChebiEntity("15903")
```

And then look at all the synonyms that the compound has:

```
chebi_entity.get_names()
> [{'_Name__name': 'beta-D-Glucose', '_Name__typ': 'SYNONYM', '_Name__source': 'KEGG COMPOUND', '_Name__adapted': False, '_Name__language': 'en'},
 {'_Name__name': 'beta-D-glucose', '_Name__typ': 'NAME', '_Name__source': 'UniProt', '_Name__adapted': False, '_Name__language': 'en'},
 {'_Name__name': 'beta-D-glucopyranose', '_Name__typ': 'IUPAC NAME', '_Name__source': 'IUPAC', '_Name__adapted': False, '_Name__language': 'en'},
 {'_Name__name': 'BETA-D-GLUCOSE', '_Name__typ': 'SYNONYM', '_Name__source': 'PDBeChem', '_Name__adapted': False, '_Name__language': 'en'},
 {'_Name__name': 'WURCS=2.0/1,1,0/[a2122h-1b_1-5]/1/', '_Name__typ': 'SYNONYM', '_Name__source': 'GlyTouCan', '_Name__adapted': False, '_Name__language': 'en'}]
```

Is there a way to get the ChEBI ID with one of  the synonyms?

```
beta-D-glucose -> 15903
```

Is there any other python tool or web-api that can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

How very interesting ...

Yes its easy just download the flat file database here:

> https://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/chebi/Flat_file_tab_delimited/names.tsv.gz

**WARNING**: it's a 5.5M file ... don't click the link unless you really want to download a file this size.

You can simply load it straight into a `pandas` dataframe from `read_csv()` and then interrogation it via `loc`. You could place the header `NAME` as the index. There are other way in, you can shift the dataframe to a dictionary and interrogate that way, or place it straight it SQL via e.g. `sqlite3`

Here I just loaded it onto Excel and found the entry you were looking for ...

[image]
....

[image]

Comment: Edited: sorry a `pandas` `iloc()` solution wasn't appropriate.